# 'std::pair' : use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-pair

I'm trying to create an unordered_map whose key would be a member of the Gdiplus::Color class and a float but i can't figure why i can't do this. This is my declaration

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair(Gdiplus::Color, float), std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen>> mymap;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've used the wrong kind of brackets for your `std::pair` type. Template arguments should be given in angle brackets:

```
std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>
```

Comment: wow. thank you. i was looking at the make_pair declaration which used ()...that explains a lot. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for instantiating the `std::pair` class template is incorrect: it should be

```
 std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>
 //       ^                     ^
```

With angular brackets instead of parentheses. Therefore, the whole declaration becomes:

```
std::unordered_map<
    std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>, 
//           ^                     ^
    std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen>
    > mymap;
```